How can i run the code for a sample of 5000 without taking forever
I'm working on estimating Maximum Likelihood Estimators (MLE) for a beta distribution using 5000 samples, each with 100 data points. However, my current implementation takes a long time to run.
This is the code i'm using:
def U_score(x, theta):
    a = theta[0]
    b = theta[1]
    n = len(x)
    epsilon = 1e-10 # to avoid log(0)
    d_a = -sp.digamma(a) + sp.digamma(a + b) + sum(np.log(x + epsilon)) / (n)
    d_b = -sp.digamma(b) + sp.digamma(a + b) + sum(np.log(1 - x + epsilon)) / (n)
    return np.array((d_a, d_b))

def Hessiana(x, theta):
    a = theta[0]
    b = theta[1]
    h11 = sp.polygamma(1, a + b) - sp.polygamma(1, a)
    h12 = sp.polygamma(1, a + b)
    h21 = sp.polygamma(1, a + b) 
    h22 = sp.polygamma(1, a + b) - sp.polygamma(1, b)
    return np.array([[h11, h12], [h21, h22]])

def H_inv(x, theta):
    H = Hessiana(x, theta)
    ridge = 1e-6  # Small constant
    H_ridge = H + ridge * np.eye(H.shape[0])
    return np.linalg.inv(H_ridge)

def max_likelihood(x, theta, tol):
    iter = 0
    while iter < 1000:
        theta_new = theta - H_inv(x, theta) @ U_score(x, theta)
        if np.linalg.norm(theta_new - theta) <= tol:
            return theta_new, iter + 1
        theta = theta_new
        iter += 1
    print('Não convergiu!')
    return theta_new, iter

def mse(arr, theta_real):
    a = theta_real[0]
    b = theta_real[1]
    eqm_a = np.mean((arr[:,0] - a)**2)
    eqm_b = np.mean((arr[:,1] - b)**2)
    return mse_a, mse_b

arr = np.array([])
n_amostras = 5000
theta = np.array([1,1])
for i in range(0, n_amostras):
    x = st.beta.rvs(2, 5, size = 100)
    emv, iteracoes = max_likelihood(x, theta, 1e-6)
    arr = np.append(arr, emv)
arr = arr.reshape(-1, 2)
print(arr)

The last part which i need to calculate is the problem:
arr = np.array([])
n_amostras = 5000
theta = np.array([1,1])
for i in range(0, n_amostras):
    x = st.beta.rvs(2, 5, size = 100)
    emv, iteracoes = max_likelihood(x, theta, 1e-6)
    arr = np.append(arr, emv)
arr = arr.reshape(-1, 2)
print(arr)

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to optimize this process and calculate the Mean Squared Error (MSE) more efficiently. Thank you!

hello, I ran your implementation and it took arpx 2.6s on my macbook (with 8 cores). Honestly for estimating MLE using sampling it is more or less good time. You can speed up the code by: 1) rewriting code in pymc and running it in jax backend; 2) or verctorizing code and replacing for loops with numpy arrays; 3) or converting your for loops and other calcualtion with jit from the numba 4) or 3) or adding mutithreading (simpler, but not so fast as other 3 methods)

Note that multithreading is generally not great due to the GIL and multiprocessing should be used instead unless the GIL can be released (eg. in Numba njit code). Also please note that nearly all Scipy functions are not available in Numba so they need to be reimplemented or you should use another external module doing that if any. Also note that sp.polygamma(1, a + b) is recomputed 4 times for no apparent reason. Same for sp.digamma(a + b). CPython is an interpreter so it optimize nearly nothing. This is your job.

@JohnnyCheesecutter Hello, i'm sorry, the problem is when n = 10.
np.random.seed(512)
arr = np.array([])
n_amostras = 5000
theta = np.array([1, 1])
for i in range(0, n_amostras):
    x = st.beta.rvs(2, 5, size=10)
    emv, iteracoes = max_likelihood(x, theta, 1e-6)
    arr = np.append(arr, emv)  
arr = arr.reshape(-1, 2)  
print(arr)

When the n = 100 it runs, but when n = 10 it just doesn't

Interesting problem, a couple of comments. (1) Simplest way to parallelize is to just execute the same script multiple times -- this evades the GIL. You would need to add a command line argument to tell each instance what part of the problem to work on. (2) You might consider initializing the iteration (I guess that's Newton's method) with an estimate obtained by a non-iterative approach, such as the method of moments. Maybe it will take fewer iterations than starting from a random point.


to calculate the Mean Squared Error (MSE) more efficiently I advise you to read this question on stack over flow Mean Squared Error in Numpy?;

instead of using python, you can use Pypy, that is a jit, you don't need to make any changes to the code;

I tried to rewrite the code without changing the logic and I managed to save around 120,000 function calls (on around 3,000,000).


Below the code:
from numpy import array, log, sum as sumnp, append, eye
from numpy.linalg import norm, inv
from scipy.stats import beta
from scipy.special import digamma, polygamma

def U_score(x, theta):
    a, b, n = theta[0], theta[1], len(x)
    = digamma(a + b)
    epsilon = 1e-10
    d_a = - digamma(a) + dig_ab + sumnp(log(x + epsilon)) / n
    d_b = - digamma(b) + dig_ab + sumnp(log(1 - x + epsilon)) / n
    return array((d_a, d_b))

def Hessiana(x, theta):
    a, b, = theta[0], theta[1]
    pol_ab = polygamma(1, a + b)
    return array([[pol_ab - polygamma(1, a), pol_ab], [pol_ab, pol_ab - polygamma(1, b)]])

def H_inv(x, theta):
    H = Hessiana(x, theta)
    return inv(H + 1e-6 * eye(H.shape[0]))

def max_likelihood(x, theta, tol):
    for cycle in range(1000):
        theta_new = theta - H_inv(x, theta) @ U_score(x, theta)
        if norm(theta_new - theta) <= tol:
            return theta_new, cycle + 1
        theta = theta_new
    raise Exception('Não convergiu!')


arr = array([])
theta = array([1, 1])
for i in range(5000):
    arr = append(arr, max_likelihood(beta.rvs(2, 5, size=100), theta, 1e-6)[0])
arr = arr.reshape(-1, 2)
print(arr)

I hope I was helpful :)
